Django RawSQL annotate field
How can i annotate field with RawSQL?
    sql_query = """
            SELECT 
                c.id, 
                COALESCE(SUM((cm.temp_min + cm.temp_max) / 2 - %s), 0) AS gdd
            FROM 
                agriculture_commune c
            LEFT JOIN 
                agriculture_communemeteo cm ON c.id = cm.commune_id
            WHERE 
                cm.date BETWEEN %s AND %s
            GROUP BY 
                c.id
        """
    communes =  communes.raw(sql_query, [TBASE, start_date, end_date])

it working , if i try do like this
communes.annotate(gdd=RawSQL(sql_query, [TBASE, start_date, end_date]))

i got error "subquery must return only one column\nLINE 1: ...mmune"

Can you share your models and what you aim to do?

As the error said, when using RawSQL to annotate a field the SQL query you provide should return only a single value per row because it's being used as part of a larger query to generate the annotated queryset.
So you need to use a query like this which returns only a single value:
SELECT 
    COALESCE(SUM((cm.temp_min + cm.temp_max) / 2 - %s), 0) AS gdd
FROM 
    agriculture_communemeteo cm
WHERE 
    cm.commune_id = agriculture_commune.id AND
    cm.date BETWEEN %s AND %s

and then annotate just as you did:
communes.annotate(gdd=RawSQL(sql_query, [TBASE, start_date, end_date]))


thanks for the answer, it worked, but unfortunately the calculation takes longer than with
    gdd_subquery = (
        CommuneMeteo.objects.filter(
            date__range=(start_date, end_date), commune_id=OuterRef("id")
        )
        .values("commune_id")
        .annotate(gdd=Sum((F("temp_min") + F("temp_max")) / 2 - TBASE))
        .values("gdd")[:1]
    )

I thought rawsql would be faster

There is no need to use a raw query this can be determined with:
from django.db.models import F, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

Commune.objects.filter(communemeteo__date__range=(start_date, end_date)).annotate(
    gdd=Coalesce(
        (F('communemeteo__temp_min') + F('communemeteo__temp_max')) / 2
        - Value(TBASE),
        0,
    )
)

thanks for the answer, but the calculation takes too long 6700ms

@Kirill: the question is if that is for this query only, and not an N+1 problem afterwards. But raw queries will not speed up the process, or at most in a marginal amount.
